# When i can use "Copy that"?

Tags: grammar, dialogue

When i can to use copy that, just to response of "do you copy" ?

tanks for your helps

Comment: Let us know if this question answers your question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/

Comment: @Frank , the link is useful but when i want to say just, i know or i understand, may i have to use "copy that" phrase?

Comment: @RegDwight, for example in one of dialog: Person-A: Did you understand? Person-B: yes, copy that. person-b may to use copy that or Not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *"copy that"* can be used in a few instances.

Regarding its literal[*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copy) sense, take the following example:

> **Secretary:** What should I do with this memorandum?
>
> **Boss:** Copy that.

As a form of [*slang*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slang), it's a [procedure word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word) in radio communications to mean that you've successfully received a transmission. Taken colloquially, it's commonly interpreted among native English speakers to mean ["*I hear you, or I understand:"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=copy%20that)

> **Friend:** The party is at 8 tonight, so be on time.
>
> **You:** Copy that.

Comment: Actually, I'll disagree with the first usage. The response of the boss would normally be "Copy it."