# When was the first documented use of "do you copy" by the military?

Tags: terminology, word-usage, military

I have found a documented use from 1960.  But WWII movies use the expression.  So are the movie people making it up, or do they know something I don't?

Comment: Is this link helpful? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/why-use-the-word-copy-in-do-you-copy-that

Comment: Here's a cite from 1955  tinyurl.com/ywzvj7ce   "How do you copy? Loud and clear, we hope, for we've got hot news for radio listeners."  Used without explanation, so we can presume it's a well-known expression before that date.

Answer (score 3):

Finding anything for this meaning of *copy* prior to @Pete 's 1955 example in a comment above is proving difficult. [Lists](https://books.google.com/books?id=15HnYySUWm4C&pg=PA53&dq=%22prowords%22%20radio%20copy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinkPHz0bv1AhWrl2oFHUWeC_wQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22prowords%22%20radio%20copy&f=false) of *prowords* or *procedure words* I've come across from the 1950's do not contain *copy* and Wikipedia articles mentioning this meaning of *copy* do not document when it began to be used. I would point out that the OED's earliest citation for *Wilco* (*Will comply*) is from 1946 (and I've found an example from [1943](https://www.google.com/books/edition/War_Department_Technical_Manual/ptoIAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=wilco&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover) in Google Books).

However, the OED does have a 1930 example of *copy* with this meaning under **read** (v.):

> **13.a.** *intransitive*. To receive and understand a message by radio (occasionally, by telephone).
>
> In most cases, formed by omission of *me* from *Do you read me?*
>
> **1930**   *Amer. Speech* 5 289   The receiving operator ‘receives’,
> ‘**copies**’ or ‘reads’.

---

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/copy) has this sense for *copy*:

**copy** (v.)

> *No object* Hear or understand someone speaking on a radio transmitter.
>
> *this is Edwards, **do you copy**, over*

as does [m-w](http://in%20radio/military%20communications%20:%20to%20acknowledge%20receipt%20of%20(a%20message)%20The%20operator%20of%20the%20Titanic%20was%20busy%20figuring%20his%20accounts%20and%20did%20not%20bother%20to%20copy%20the%20message.%20A%20little%20later%20in%20the%20afternoon,%20another%20ship%20named%20the%20Baltic%20called%20the%20Titanic%20to%20tell%20her%20about%20icebergs%20that%20were%20in%20her%20way.%20%E2%80%94%20Rev.%20Robert%20P.%20Lawrence):

> *In radio/military communications*: to acknowledge receipt of (a message)
>
> *The operator of the Titanic was busy figuring his accounts and did not bother to **copy** the message. A little later in the afternoon,
> another ship named the Baltic called the Titanic to tell her about
> icebergs that were in her way.* — Rev. Robert P. Lawrence

However, I don't see it in the OED under the verb *copy*.

Comment: It might have originated in telegraphy, where the receiving telegraph operator would "copy" the coded message onto paper.

Comment: @Robusto I think it's almost a given that *copy* was first used that way. I've seen "Ready to copy."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it comes from french "compris" , which means "understood"

Likewise mayday "m'aider" (help me)

Comment: 'Mayday' is phonetically similar to 'm'aidez' - what is the connection between 'compris' and "(do you) copy"?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439227)